# Join two YouTube videos

Tags: youtube

Maybe I overlooked the YouTube editor but I was trying to see if there are options in YouTube editor to join two previously uploaded videos together to create a new one. Please let me know if such a feature exists.

If there is no such option, what would you suggest for videos that are already uploaded so that the video quality of the final (joined) video is preserved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you own the videos, or they are licensed under a creative commons license on YouTube then you will be able to combine them with the editor. Follow the steps below to do so:

1. **Navigate to the video editor** `Video Manager -> Video Editor` [image: Video Editor]
2. **Now that you are in the editor select two videos (or more) and drag them into the timeline one at a time.**[image: Merging]
3. **Proceed to name your video and hit publish** [image: Publish Merged Videos]

Now all you have to do is wait for the videos to process and you should be good to go with a merged video.